# Firebase addValueEvent is triggered but not updating in remote console

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have created a simple android application with Firebase realtime database free account as backend. I was enabled offline capability using `setPersistanceEnabled(true)`. But I disabled this today but the set value is not getting reflected in the remote as well as the `ValueEventListener` is not getting fired for remote items.

Can anyone help me to check where the issue is?

After this issue, I have created a new test android application but that app also having the same issue. The code is shown below

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true)
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val myRef = database.getReference("message")

        database.getReference("message").addValueEventListener(this)

        myRef.setValue("Hello, World!")
        myRef.setValue("Hello, World!123")
        Log.d("XXXXX", "Initialized")
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
    }

    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        Log.d("XXXXX", "value change")
    }
}
```

build.gradle - app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shafeeque.firebasetest"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

Output log

```
2020-09-04 17:00:46.664 14090-14090/com.shafeeque.firebasetest D/XXXXX: Initialized
2020-09-04 17:00:46.878 14090-14090/com.shafeeque.firebasetest D/XXXXX: value change
2020-09-04 17:00:46.881 14090-14090/com.shafeeque.firebasetest D/XXXXX: value change
```

***Update***
I tried after removing android studio completely and re-installed. Still the issue is there

Please find my Firebase log

```
2020-09-05 16:13:26.010 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
2020-09-05 16:13:26.014 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 0ms
2020-09-05 16:13:26.027 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Listening on message (params: {})
2020-09-05 16:13:26.027 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Adding listen query: message (params: {})
2020-09-05 16:13:26.027 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/RepoOperation: Auth token changed, triggering auth token refresh
2020-09-05 16:13:26.027 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Auth token refreshed.
2020-09-05 16:13:26.027 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/RepoOperation: set: /message
2020-09-05 16:13:26.027 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/DataOperation: set: /message Hello, World!
2020-09-05 16:13:26.029 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/EventRaiser: Raising 1 event(s)
2020-09-05 16:13:26.030 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/RepoOperation: Aborting transactions for path: /message. Affected: /message
2020-09-05 16:13:26.031 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
2020-09-05 16:13:26.031 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening connection
2020-09-05 16:13:26.035 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/Connection: conn_0 - Opening a connection
2020-09-05 16:13:26.404 26502-26502/com.example.firebaseapplication D/EventRaiser: Raising /message: VALUE: Hello, World!
2020-09-05 16:13:56.037 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/WebSocket: ws_0 - timed out on connect
2020-09-05 16:13:56.038 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/WebSocket: ws_0 - closed
2020-09-05 16:13:56.038 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/WebSocket: ws_0 - closing itself
2020-09-05 16:13:56.038 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/Connection: conn_0 - Realtime connection failed
2020-09-05 16:13:56.038 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/Connection: conn_0 - closing realtime connection
2020-09-05 16:13:56.038 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Got on disconnect due to OTHER
2020-09-05 16:13:56.039 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
2020-09-05 16:13:56.039 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 669ms
2020-09-05 16:13:56.710 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
2020-09-05 16:13:56.710 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening connection
2020-09-05 16:13:56.712 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/Connection: conn_1 - Opening a connection
2020-09-05 16:14:26.715 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/WebSocket: ws_1 - timed out on connect
2020-09-05 16:14:26.715 26502-26547/com.example.firebaseapplication D/WebSocket: ws_1 - closed
```

Comment: Any idea about the usage limit of free project in firebase?

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you have something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @alex mamo You mean in on the failure listener?

Comment: Try to log the error message from `override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError)`.

Comment: The control does not get into the onCancelled callback function

Comment: Ok, `onCancelled` is not triggered, how about `onDataChange`? Is it?

Comment: OnDatachange is getting triggered. But data is not updating in firebase console

Comment: @Alex Mamo, Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, no idea so far.

Comment: @AlexMamo, Somehow it's timed out. Can you check the firebase log updated?

Comment: No clue regarding what can produce this behavior. Maybe you should write to the Firebase team.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote to Firebase team, and got the response as

```
    If this request is because you are having issues with your RTDB, 
let me inform you that we've seen multiple reports about similar issues, 
and from what we have found so far is that this is related to a network
issue and specifically to an internet provider. According to these reports,
this happens only with Reliance Jio or Vodafone networks
```

Currently, I am using Vodafone, and today onwards, it seems the issue has been sorted out.

Thankyou Alex Mamo for your help